# Webroot system permisssions

Tags: c++, powershell, permissions, access-denied

We have a new client with Webroot installed and the previous IT company is useless in removing our clients using their web console.

We are looking at installing our antivirus, but we cannot do so with webroot still installed. I have ran PowerShell command after PowerShell command trying to remove Webroots contents from the device, yet even when using PowerShell as Sys32 permissions are still denied from removing Webroot and its contents. Without using Hiren's or gandalfs and the likes, how can this be removed and permission be granted to remove this? Can this be written in C++ or any other language? Can it be performed with PowerShell? If so, how can I force the device to give full permissions to remove what I want from the device?

Comment: What product from [Webroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webroot#History)? *"SecureAnywhere AntiVirus"*?

Comment: This is more of a permissions issue rather than code. Take ownership of the program, or strip it of permissions.

Comment: I've tried taking ownership of the program, even from the sysadmin profile and permission is still denied, even ran Psexec from powershell to get sys32 permissions and was still denied access.

Comment: Taking ownership from security settings is not an option, i've tried that already. I have run Revo uninstaller as well as UnlockIT plus multiple tools to try remove it and nothing seems to work, keep in mind everything i've done was done remotely, i know if i physically set the device to restart in safe mode or boot from a live windows PE then i can more than likely remove the software. I want an alternative to safe boot without networking or an alternative to booting the device with Hiren's or Gandalf's

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes it is webroot SecureAnywhere Antivirus but the enterprise edition